# How to align two text in extreme ends (left and right) in a Single Button View android

Tags: android

I have a button for showing list of items in a different popup
In that button, I want a text as a label which is left aligned and a text on the right side which would be dynamically added depending on the item selected from the popup

How to align these two texts on a single button? I'm new to android.

Tried giving different ascii characters as spaces but didn't help

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Expected Result

```
[**Name**                    john] ---- single button view with two texts
```

[image]

Comment: A sample image will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your button and textviews withhin a frame layout, along with elevation to display the textviews over the button :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note: android:outlineProvider="none" will remove the shadow on the textviews that the elevation provides.

[image]

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as answered thankyou.

Comment: is there any other way, i dont want to use a custom layout, as if i use a custom layout, the click on that button is not working, Can you post a working code or give some alternative

Comment: I wouldnt put textviews ontop of a button, i would follow Material Design guidelines.
However if this is what youre after then you can set an 
`android:onClick="methodName"` along with `android:clickable="true"` to the wrapping layout, i would disable click actions on the button also (or remove the button) `android:clickable="false"`.